# How to get a class name plus function name but no args in c++ that is able to handle template function, c function, static function, etc?

Tags: c++, c++17

Hi I know this is an old topic: how to get c++ function name. But I really did not see a satisfactory answer.

I am using c++17 so c++20 feature does not apply to me.

I need a solid way that is able to print "class_name::func_name()" for functions inside a class (both static and instance method), and "func_name()" for c style functions.

The method must handle all kinds of cases:

1. template functions.
2. skip all args. Sometimes an arg has "()" in it, for example, an arg of type std::function<void()>, so it's hard to parse.
3. static functions and instance functions
4. nested classes

I tried `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__func__`, and tried parsing them with some code. I am not seeing a way that really works for all cases.

Thanks.

Comment: There's simply nothing in the standard C++ library that does this.

Comment: `__func__` is the best you can get, but it is still not what you wish for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik C++23 will have https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/basic_stacktrace. [C++ weekly on stacktrace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IcxniCxKlQ)

Comment: depending on what you need it for [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) might be of help

Comment: btw I dont understand "so it's hard to parse". You just need to look for the first `(` and the last `)`, no?

Comment: sometimes the argument is of type: std::function<void()>, so it messed up with the parsing logic that depends on the location of left and right parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) to get an implementation defined string describing the function names etc.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

void log(std::ostream& os = std::cout,
         const std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    os << loc.file_name() << '(' << loc.line() << "): "
       << loc.function_name() << '\n';
}

class Foo {
public:
    void func() const {
        log();
    }
};

int main() {
    log();
    
    Foo f;
    f.func();
}
```

Possible output (gcc and llvm happens to agree in this case):

```
/app/example.cpp(16): int main()
/app/example.cpp(11): void Foo::func() const
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y8WGjYjYP)

---

In C++17, if you use the gcc implementation of the standard library, you can use the `experimental/source_location`:

```cpp
#include <experimental/source_location>
#include <iostream>

void log(std::ostream& os = std::cout,
         const std::experimental::source_location loc =
             std::experimental::source_location::current())
{
    os << loc.file_name() << '(' << loc.line() << "): "
       << loc.function_name() << '\n';
}

class Foo {
   public:
    void func() const { log(); }
};

int main() {
    log();

    Foo f;
    f.func();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a (since C++20) solution

Comment: @DachuanHuang  Sorry, I missed the C++17 bit but added a possible workaround for that.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the experimental source location feature in cpp17. It does not have a class_name field, unfortunately.